# Component is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module (lazy loading)

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, ng-modules

I am working on Angular7 application and getting a strange error that my Component 'x' is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.

**Group Module:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { GroupRoutingModule } from './group-routing.module';
import { GroupComponent } from './group/group.component';
import { GroupListComponent } from './group-list/group-list.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [

   GroupComponent,
   GroupListComponent 

  ],
  imports: [

     CommonModule,
     FormsModule,
     GroupRoutingModule

  ],
  exports: [
    GroupComponent,
    GroupListComponent 
  ]
})
export class GroupModule { }
```

**User Module:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CorrCommonModule } from '../../../common/common.module';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';
import { UserRoutingModule } from './user-routing.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    UserComponent    
  ],
  entryComponents: [
  ],
  imports: [
     CommonModule,
     FormsModule,
     UserRoutingModule
  ],
  exports: [
    UserComponent        
  ]
})
export class UserModule { }
```

**Both of these modules are then added in Security module which is lazy loaded module.**

**Security Module:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { SecurityRoutingModule } from './security-routing.module';
import { UserModule } from './components/user/user.module';
import { GroupModule } from './components/group/group.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
    entryComponents: [
    ],
    exports: [
    ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    SecurityRoutingModule,
    GroupModule,
    UserModule
  ],
  providers: []
})
export class SecurityModule {}
```

**User-Routing Module:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';
import { GroupListComponent } from '../group/group-list/group-list.component';

const Routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'user',
    component: UserComponent
    },
     {
       path: 'group',
       component: GroupListComponent
     }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(Routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class UserRoutingModule { }
```

Now when I use GroupListComponent in User-Routing module, I am getting the issue that **Component is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module**

**EDIT**

This module also use similar approach but there isn't such issue.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CountryComponent } from './country/country.component';
import { CurrencyListComponent } from '../currency/currency-list/currency-list.component';
import { SetupLogComponent } from '../log/setup-log/setup-log.component';
import { RegionListComponent } from '../region/region-list/region-list.component';
import { CityPlaceListComponent } from '../city-place/city-place-list/city-place-list.component';




const Routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'country',
    component: CountryComponent
  },
  {
     path: '', pathMatch: 'full',
     component: CountryDetailComponent
     },
     {
     path: 'region',
     component: RegionListComponent
     },
     {
     path: 'currency',
     component: CurrencyListComponent
     },
     {
     path: 'cityplace',
     component: CityPlaceListComponent
     }];




@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(Routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: []
})
export class CountryRoutingModule { }
```

**EDIT 2:**
A part of code from app route

```
{path: 'security',  loadChildren: './modules/security/security.module#SecurityModule', data: { preload: true }},
{path: 'setup', loadChildren: './modules/setup/setup.module#SetupModule', data: { preload: true }},
```

Comment: @GouravGarg, I am using lazyloading for those modules so I specify that.

Comment: Can I see your GroupRoutingModule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now when I use GroupListComponent in User-Routing module, I am getting the issue that Component is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module

Your UserRoutingModule doesn't import the `GroupModule` ence why you cannot use it.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [GroupModule, RouterModule.forChild(Routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class UserRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: I cann't understand why this issue resolve after doing so. While similar approach is being used in another application and there isn't any such issue while we haven't include modules in routing module.

Comment: I have added another routing module where no such issue is arising.